# How to find the minimum value in a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy, minimum

Hey this is a quick and easy question...
How would i find the minimum value of this matrix, excluding 0?
As in, 8

```
arr = numpy.array([[  0.,  56.,  20.,  44.],
                   [ 68.,   0.,  56.,   8.],
                   [ 32.,  56.,   0.,  44.],
                   [ 68.,  20.,  56.,   0.]])
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you're using `numpy`, you could use

```
arr[arr>0].min()
```

for the case you posted. 
but if your array could have negative values, then you should use

```
arr[arr != 0].min()
```

Comment: @Sean: no, I used `arr` as the name of your array. You didn't specify one.

Comment: @Justanotherdunce: ya - while I agree that some simple questions could do with more research on the OPs part, in this case people unfamiliar with matrix manipulation (matlab, numpy style) could find it difficult to get the min that isn't 0.